# Essential supremum is actually a minimum

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a measurable funcion, we define $$\lVert f \rVert_\infty=\inf\left\{a\ge 0\;:\;\mu\left(\{x\;:\; |f(x)|>a\}\right)=0\right\}.$$ We observe that the infimum is actually attained, for

$$\{x\;:\; |f(x)|>a\}=\bigcup_1^\infty\{x\;:\; |f(x)|>a+n^{-1}\},$$

and if the sets on the right are null, so is the one on the left.

I did not understand why this explanation is sufficient to show that it is a minimum. Could someone explain it to me? Thank you.

Thanks!

Comment: It just says that this set of $a$'s (over which you are taking the infimum) doesn't only have an infimum but has the minimum. I.e. the infimum is in the set, i.e. it is attained.

Comment: Please don't rely on images. [Type your formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: @donaastorThanks, but I understood that. What I don't understand is the explanation. Why write the set as that union?

Comment: @AnneBauvalExcuse me, I'm rewriting it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $a=\|f\|_\infty.$ Then, $\forall b>a\quad\mu(\{x:|f(x)|>b\})=0.$ In particular, $$\forall n\in\Bbb N\quad\mu(A_n)=0,\quad\text{where}\quad A_n=\{x:|f(x)|>a+1/n\}.$$
Now,
$$|f(x)|>a\iff \exists n\in\Bbb N\quad x\in A_n$$
hence
$$\mu(\{x:|f(x)|>a\})=\mu\left(\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N} A_n\right)=0.$$